# requirejs include multiple extensions for jquery control

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

How do you load other extensions for a jquery control called 'fancytree' I'm trying to get fancytee to load or include the fancytree.table.js and other extensions that are needed - below is my config

```
require.config({

    shim: {

        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery-ui': {
            exports: "$",
            deps: ['jquery']
        },  
        'fancytree': {
            deps: ['jquery-ui']
        }, 
        'alertify': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'fancytreetable': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'fancytree']
        }
    },

    paths: {
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery',
        'underscore': '../lib/underscore/underscore',
        'backbone': '../lib/backbone/backbone',     
        'text': '../lib/text/text',
        'jquery-ui': '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui',
        'fancytree': [      
            '../vendor/fancytree/fancytree',
            '../vendor/fancytree/fancytree.table'/* this extension here needs to be added but it's not included */
        ],          
        'alertify': '../vendor/alertify/alertify'       
    },

    baseUrl: '/js/app',

});
```

Comment: Paths options just for developers convenience in order to write minimal code. Not to specify dependency. You should create two different path variables. Since you have already defined shim for it only defining path for '../vendor/fancytree/fancytree.table' will suffice. Unless of course you need '../vendor/fancytree/fancytree' as seperate dependancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nikhil Mehta's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733686/requirejs-include-multiple-extensions-for-jquery-control#comment68697888_40733686) points you in the right direction. Your `paths` value for `fancytree` is wrong. You use an array there when you want to provide fallback values for modules. If you give `[A, B, C]`, for instance, if `A` fails to load, RequireJS tries `B` and if this fails, tries `C`. And if all fail, then that's a load failure.

Based on the configuration you show, you'd need:

```
fancytree: '../vendor/fancytree/fancytree',
fancytreetable: '../vendor/fancytree/fancytree.table'
```

You already have a `shim` that establishes that `fancytreetable` needs `fancytree`.

Note that unless you are using fairly old versions of Underscore and Backbone, you do not need to specify `shim` values for them. RequireJS is probably going to just ignore them but it may confuse people reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how made it work, requirejs with `jquery.fancytree-all` and latest `jquery-ui` with AMD support, since working with individual extensions will require a lot of shimming.

`onBuildWrite` is optional but i prefer it this way

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': './js/vendor/jquery',
    'jquery-ui': './js/vendor/jquery-ui',
    'jquery.fancytree': './js/vendor/fancytree/jquery.fancytree-all'
  },
  shim: {
    'jquery.fancytree': {
      deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui/core', 'jquery-ui/effect', 'jquery-ui/effects/effect-blind', 'jquery-ui/widgets/draggable', 'jquery-ui/widgets/droppable'],
      exports: 'jQuery.fn.fancytree'
    }
  },
  onBuildWrite: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    'use strict';
    if (moduleName === 'jquery.fancytree') {
      contents = 'define( "jquery.fancytree", ["jquery", "jquery-ui/core", "jquery-ui/effect", "jquery-ui/effects/effect-blind", "jquery-ui/widgets/draggable", "jquery-ui/widgets/droppable"], function(jQuery) { ' + contents + '});';
    }
    return contents;
  }
});

// usage 
 define([
     'jquery',
     'jquery.fancytree',
     'css!./css/fancytree/skin-custom/ui.fancytree.css',
   ],
   function($) {
     'use strict';
     //
     $('#tree').fancytree({
       checkbox: true,
       source: [{title: 'Node 1'}, {title: 'Node 2',key: 'id2'}]
     });
     //
   });
//
```